# Noise/Buzz when recording with TC Helicon Voice Live 2

Tags: music

I keep getting buzz/noise when I'm recording vox with the Voicelive 2. My chain is Fet 47 > TC Helicon > Duet > Computer.

I've played around with Line vs Mic IOs but the same noise is there regardless of the settings. Could this be a power supply issue? I don't fully understand this but have read some other articles that are sorta similar. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just want a clean vocal recording with the TC Helicon dry fx.

Thanks!

Comment: Laptop or desktop, grounded or ungrounded power supply?

Comment: Desktop. The helicon has a two prong outlet connection. It is plugged into the same powerstrip as the computer.

Comment: OK, you may have to investigate grounding wiring, straps between devices' cases. I've never worked with un-eartherd mains, it's illegal where I live.

Answer (score 0):

Going around to all places I can find with this similar issue. I’ve managed to fix mine, so I hope other people can reap the reward of my trouble shooting.

My setup was that I was plugging my Mic Mechanic into JBL 310. The issue I was having was that it was a balanced output leaving the helicon, going into an unbalanced input. The noise is extra signal that time input device doesn’t know what to do with. The solution is to turn the balanced signal into an unbalanced signal. I plugged the helicon into a passive di in reverse (helicon into output of di, then the input of the di into the JBL with a ts (guitar) lead. Fixed. Note it has to be a passive di to work in reverse

Check what you are plugging the helicon into. If you are plugging into an unbalanced input, this is your issue and the above is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

My Voicelive play exhibits low hum when connected to any and all my preamps in my recording setup. When I unplug the Voicelive play the hum is gone so it most likely is related to the power supply. My system is RME UFX II and Ferrofish Pulse and SSL Six preamps. All other sources input into my system are dead quiet, mics, keyboards, and bass. The Voicelive play would probably be ok for live performances in a stage scenario but in my studio it stands out like a sore thumb with the low hum. I wish there was a remedy since it’s money spent based on reviews by other users.